# Channel creation fails with Hyperledger fabric through cli?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I am trying to build up a blockchain network from scratch using Hyperledger fabric. After creating crypto-config and channel artifacts and also changing the respective attribute in .ymal files I up the containers then when I try to create a channel through CLI it leaves me this error on console.

> Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from
>   directory
>   //opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/users/Admin@doctor.pms.com/msp:
>   Setup error: nil conf reference

This is my docker-compose-base.yaml file.

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:

  orderer.pms.com:
    container_name: orderer.pms.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/pms.com/orderers/orderer.pms.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/pms.com/orderers/orderer.pms.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.pms.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:
    container_name: peer0.generalpublic.pms.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.generalpublic.pms.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=GeneralpublicMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/generalpublic.pms.com/peers/peer0.generalpublic.pms.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/generalpublic.pms.com/peers/peer0.generalpublic.pms.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:
    container_name: peer1.generalpublic.pms.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.generalpublic.pms.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=GeneralpublicMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/generalpublic.pms.com/peers/peer1.generalpublic.pms.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/generalpublic.pms.com/peers/peer1.generalpublic.pms.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    ports:
      - 8051:8051

  peer0.doctor.pms.com:
    container_name: peer0.doctor.pms.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.doctor.pms.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.doctor.pms.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.doctor.pms.com:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.doctor.pms.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.doctor.pms.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DoctorMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/peers/peer0.doctor.pms.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/peers/peer0.doctor.pms.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.doctor.pms.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:9051

  peer1.doctor.pms.com:
    container_name: peer1.doctor.pms.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.doctor.doctor.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.doctor.pms.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.doctor.pms.com:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.doctor.pms.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.doctor.pms.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DoctorMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/peers/peer1.doctor.pms.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/peers/peer1.doctor.pms.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.doctor.pms.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 10051:10051
```

This is my docker-compose-cli.yaml file.

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.pms.com:
  peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:
  peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:
  peer0.doctor.pms.com:
  peer1.doctor.pms.com:
  ca.Generalpublic.pms.com:
  ca.doctor.pms.com:


networks:
  byfn:

services:
  ca.generalpublic.pms.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.generalpublic.pms.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.generalpublic.pms.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/929794a7d5a90f2fc4f2dbc53db66d27cba02f8efbed28ff1d14001e862a3574_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.generalpublic.pms.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/929794a7d5a90f2fc4f2dbc53db66d27cba02f8efbed28ff1d14001e862a3574_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/generalpublic.pms.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.generalpublic.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca.doctor.pms.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.doctor.pms.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.doctor.pms.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/5c238614a373e903f982d5735db36fad9f2a2c5ce42fc6a9a3df6628a91657e4_sk
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.doctor.pms.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/5c238614a373e903f982d5735db36fad9f2a2c5ce42fc6a9a3df6628a91657e4_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.doctor.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn


  orderer.pms.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.pms.com
    container_name: orderer.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.generalpublic.pms.com:
    container_name: peer0.generalpublic.pms.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.generalpublic.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.generalpublic.pms.com:
    container_name: peer1.generalpublic.pms.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.generalpublic.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.doctor.pms.com:
    container_name: peer0.doctor.pms.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.doctor.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.doctor.pms.com:
    container_name: peer1.doctor.pms.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.doctor.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      # - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.doctor.pms.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DoctorMSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/peers/peer0.doctor.pms.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/peers/peer0.doctor.pms.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/peers/peer0.doctor.pms.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/users/Admin@doctor.pms.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.pms.com
      - peer0.generalpublic.pms.com
      - peer1.generalpublic.pms.com
      - peer0.doctor.pms.com
      - peer1.doctor.pms.com
      - ca.generalpublic.pms.com
      - ca.doctor.pms.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

I try to find out a solution to this problem on the internet but I was unable to find an exact solution to this problem. Can someone help me to find out a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please make sure that Admin user Certificate is available in CLI container at the location
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/users/Admin@doctor.pms.com

Comment: @PAVAN It is there

Comment: `root@13424642fb6c:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.pms.com/users/Admin@doctor.pms.com/msp# ls
admincerts  cacerts  config.yaml  keystore  signcerts  tlscacerts`

Comment: Please set the logging level to info so that you will get additional information.
It's related to blockchain cryptography service provider and not able to find MSP.